# Drupal Signup: how to signup to multiple events at once?

Tags: 7, users

I've been looking all over the internet for this, but couldn't find anything about it. The thing is like this:

I am creating a Drupal 7 website for a training institute. On the website I am showing the trainings in a calendar with the Calendar, Views and Date modules (see also http://drupal.org/node/998334#part1 )

With the Signup module users can signup for a single training by leaving their name, address, etc. But I would like to make it possible to signup for multiple events at once. The available events should be listed on the signup page and can individually be checked. The user will then be signed up for all the selected events with only once filling in the form.

Does anybody know if there is a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Someone put together a hacky solution for "Signup" module (which is apparently similar to "CCK Signup"). Maybe it's a good starting point: http://drupal.org/node/151898.